# Upload Word File => Use TinyMCE to convert contents to well-formed HTML => Insert into TinyMCE

Tags: ms-word, tinymce, .doc

Has anyone experimented with allowing users to upload a word file (.doc, or .docx), and use TinyMCE to do the Word => HTML conversion? (And ultimately place the converted HTML in the editor) I'd like to use TinyMCE for this conversion because it is so good at translating Word formatting to HTML.

From what I've read, the difficulty with this seems to be that by default TinyMCE handles System Clipboard => HTML very well, but not raw .doc(x) => HTML. I haven't yet found any utilities for the .doc(x) => System Clipboard operation. I'd love to hear about solutions out there!

This seems to be the most similar question, but it does not seems to have found an answer: [Transfer Word Document Contents to Web Environment on Server Side Using C# ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991912/transfer-word-document-contents-to-web-environment-on-server-side-using-c-sharp)